# Given a number $N$ and a prime $P$, how many numbers $\leq N$ are divisable by P but not by any smaller primes?

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization

The following Math Exchange question deals with a similar problem:

[Not divisible by $2,3$ or $5$ but divisible by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451298/not-divisible-by-2-3-or-5-but-divisible-by-7)

However, the answers given become infeasible quite quickly because the amount of permutations increases too rapidly as P grows.

Comment: It doesn't become infeasible _sooo_ quickly, because the products of primes in the inclusion-exclusion grow pretty fast. What sort of $N$ and $P$ are you interested in?

Comment: I'm working with N in the range of 10^9 and P in the range of 10^4, for example.

Comment: Then you have around $1000$ primes less than $P$ to consider, and the products of such primes you need to consider do not exceed about $10^5$. That's products of at most six primes. With a good dynamic programming approach to break out as soon as you can, that is feasible. At least unless you have very tight time constraints. If you don't need an exact count and an approximation suffices, Mertens' third theorem becomes relevant.

Comment: I considered applying Merten's third theorem but I figured inclusion-exclusion would yield a better answer.

Comment: Wait. The quotient $N/P$ is only about $10^5$, when $P$ is near the upper end. That calls for sieving. Take the DP approach when $P$ is smaller.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need to calculate the answer for every prime <= P (I'm assuming the problem itself can't be simplified with this data, though maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: With those sizes of N and P any such number will be a product of P and one prime in the range $[P, N/P]$, since even $P^3 > N$.

Comment: So you need the count of $n \leqslant N$ with smallest prime factor $p$ for all $p \leqslant P$? Sieve it.

Comment: There are some efficient implementations of the Legendre Phi function (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendresFormula.html) which could work for this.  The can get the answer for your range in a few milliseconds.